# plot power spectrum of a signal with wavelet transform

Tags: python, librosa, wavelet, wavelet-transform, pywavelets

Using this dataset https://philharmonia.co.uk/resources/sound-samples/ I'm trying to plot the power spectrum of note played by a specific instrument.

I'm using librosa to load the audio file and get some information with this code

```
import librosa
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pywt

y, sr = librosa.load(file_path)
duration = librosa.get_duration(y=y, sr=sr)
delta_t = duration / len(y)
t0=0
time = np.arange(0, len(y)) * delta_t + t0
```

I'm also following this https://ataspinar.com/2018/12/21/a-guide-for-using-the-wavelet-transform-in-machine-learning/ guide to plot the power spectrum and I'm using pywavelet library.

The problem that I have with this code is RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log2 and the plot is not shown.

```
def plot_wavelet(time, signal, scales, 
                 waveletname = 'cmor', 
                 cmap = plt.cm.seismic, 
                 title = 'Wavelet Transform (Power Spectrum) of signal', 
                 ylabel = 'Period (years)', 
                 xlabel = 'Time'):
    
    dt = time[1] - time[0]
    print("dt ", dt)
    [coefficients, frequencies] = pywt.cwt(signal, scales, waveletname, dt)
    power = (abs(coefficients)) ** 2
    period = 1. / frequencies
    levels = [0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8]
    contourlevels = np.log2(levels)
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
    im = ax.contourf(time, np.log2(period), np.log2(power), contourlevels, extend='both',cmap=cmap)
    

    ax.set_title(title, fontsize=20)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel, fontsize=18)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel, fontsize=18)
    
    yticks = 2**np.arange(np.ceil(np.log2(period.min())), np.ceil(np.log2(period.max())))
    ax.set_yticks(np.log2(yticks))
    ax.set_yticklabels(yticks)
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ylim = ax.get_ylim()
    ax.set_ylim(ylim[0], -1)
    
    cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.95, 0.5, 0.03, 0.25])
    fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax, orientation="vertical")
    plt.show()

scales = np.arange(1, 128)
plot_wavelet(time=time, signal=y, scales=scales, waveletname='gaus5')
```

Noting that some values in the power array are at -inf.
How can I solve?